# I am uploading images to cloudinary onChange but having challenges saving the response images urls as a state array or object

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

After my images have been uploaded my response returns secured images urls. However i want to save the urls as an array or object of image urls as they are for my products gallery.

```
 const multipleFilesUpload = async (files) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i];
      formData.append("file", file);
      formData.append("upload_preset", "kwingy");

      axios
        .post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/kwjsjsy/image/upload", formData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data.secure_url);
        });
    }
  };
```

When the images are uploaded its logging the urls of the multiple images. How do i save the urls as a state array or object as i will want to pass it to my database later on.......

**below is my console log response**

https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648607946/tudifdsk2j0dy7tpumze.png index.tsx:48:18
https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648607947/f8ylw5iwlaajzhjqr5ld.png index.tsx:48:18
https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648607946/kpyqcxxgysumahggerom.png index.tsx:48:18

​

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure the code to queue up the uploads, run them concurrently, then pull out the secure links and write them to your DB. Something like this:

```
  const multipleFilesUpload = async (files) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    const postPromises = []
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i];
      formData.append("file", file);
      formData.append("upload_preset", "kwingy");
      postPromises.push(axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/kwjsjsy/image/upload", formData))
    }
    try {
      const results = await Promise.all(postPromises)
      // Now pull out the urls and write to your DB...
      console.log('secure_urls', results.map(({data:{secure_url}})=>secure_url))
    } catch (error) {
        // if any of the uploads fail, they all fail
        console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

You could put the values into a state variable:

```
// state variable to hold your values
const [secureUrls] = useState([])

const multipleFilesUpload = async (files) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i];
      formData.append("file", file);
      formData.append("upload_preset", "kwingy");

      axios
        .post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/kwjsjsy/image/upload", formData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data.secure_url);
          // add url to the array of urls
          secureUrls.push(response.data.secure_url)
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: thank you Dave. Ok well understood. How about if for now i want to save them as a state eg setImgUrls ... because my code for adding them to the database is seperate as it has many other state values

Comment: Just make a state variable to hold the urls and push them in when you get them. But then later you need to know if all the uploads have completed, etc...

Comment: Happy to help. If that works, put a green check by the answer to accept it.

Comment: ok noted thanks

Comment: how do i put a green